# Sails Js Destroy record

Tags: javascript, sails.js

I want to remove a record from my SQL database. And it's strenge because, when I try to find the record, I get it with success. But When I try to remove it, I have an error.

```
Service.find({id:serviceId}).exec(function(err, srv){

  if(err){res.json({err:err})}

  // some script to verify if the user can remove this record 
  // ....

  if(canRemove){

    Service.destroy({id: serviceId}).exec(function(err){
      if(err){res.json({err:err})}
      res.json('record removed');
    })

  }

})
```

Did I miss something?

EDIT: the error:
[image]

Comment: What's the error you are having?

Comment: I edit the post with the error @yBrodsky

Comment: That's one weird error, beats me. That Waterline (Sails ORM) is a piece of crap to be honest.

Comment: Totally agree @yBrodsky, it know how to make people frustrated :x

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have finaly found the solution.

Because when I changed the "return res.serverError('Something went wrong')" by "return res.serverError(err)" I had this message :

```
Error (E_UNKNOWN) :: Encountered an unexpected error
: ER_BAD_FIELD_ERROR: Champ 'model.undefined' unknown in order clause
at ....
```

So I make some research and edit my Service Model by adding an primary key as @sgress454 said in this post: [Cannot update attributes in Sails.js model instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25129742/cannot-update-attributes-in-sails-js-model-instance) and then I be able to remove the record perfectly.

Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 0):

Code seems to be crashing at `res.json` in `if(err)` block.

Change this code:

```
Service.destroy({id: serviceId}).exec(function(err){
  if(err){res.json({err:err})}
  res.json('record removed');
})
```

to this:

```
Service.destroy({id: serviceId}).exec(function(err){
  if(err){
    // sails.log.error('Error', err);
    return res.serverError('Something went wrong');
  }
  res.json('record removed');
})
```

Comment: Hi @Sangharsh, even with this changement I still have an error ( now it's the res.serverError ) .. Is it possible that I have it because of my sails models migrate is "safe"?

Comment: Just confirming, did you use `'Something went wrong'` in place of `{err:err}`? Because most likely your err object is circular and hence giving troubling in serialization.

Comment: I'm not sure about your question but yes, I've change the {err:err} by 'Something went wrong', but  the error I have look like you said..